# Uncaught TypeError, 500 Internal Server Error, and Error 1101 while trying to deploy a worker in Cloudflare

Tags: javascript, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I am using https://www.craft.do/ as a note-taking app. It has the ability to publish notes online so I want to use it to publish an online collection of notes, which I did here: https://www.craft.do/s/DNUP0iZyULDr15. However, I want to use a custom domain before the thread of random numbers and letters as in something like https://test-site.com/s/DNUP0iZyULDr15. Craft currently does not support custom domains. But a developer created a workaround here: https://zuolan.me/craft_custom_domain_en#64abd1d780c247d8a5fd9678e1d0ec80.

His solution basically uses a script that runs through a worker/service in Cloudflare. This is the script:

```js
// Your domain name
const MY_DOMAIN = 'knu-salin.vinceimbat.workers.dev'

// Website language
const LANG = 'en'

// Favicon url
const FAVICON_URL = 'https://example.com/favicon.ico'

// Your config page link
const CONFIG_URL = 'https://www.craft.do/s/9Q1QIOQrvZNnNf'

// Your Telegram Token and ID
const TG_TOKEN = ""
const TG_CHAT_ID = ""

// END

// Default function
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(fetchAndApply(event.request))
})

// Fetch url
async function fetchAndApply(request) {
  let url = new URL(request.url)
  // Set upstream domain
  url.host = 'www.craft.do'
  let pathname = url.pathname
  let response = null

  const config_obj = await configParser()

  // Automatically generate robots.txt and sitemap.xml
  if (pathname === '/robots.txt') {
    return new Response('Sitemap: https://' + MY_DOMAIN + '/sitemap.xml')
  }
  if (pathname === '/sitemap.xml') {
    let sitemap = '<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">'
    for(var path in config_obj){
      sitemap += '<url><loc>https://' + MY_DOMAIN + '/' + path + '</loc></url>'
    }
    sitemap += '</urlset>'
    response = new Response(sitemap)
    response.headers.set('content-type', 'application/xml')
    return response
  }
  if (pathname === '/favicon.svg') {
    response = new Response('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100pt" height="100pt" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><g fill="blue" transform="translate(0.000000,100) scale(0.080000,-0.080000)"><path d="M762 1203 c-6 -15 -13 -46 -17 -68 -4 -22 -13 -49 -20 -61 -15 -23 -122 -69 -257 -109 -49 -14 -88 -28 -88 -29 0 -2 33 -20 73 -40 49 -24 87 -36 115 -36 28 0 42 -4 42 -13 0 -34 -295 -517 -390 -639 -40 -52 -4 -28 86 56 49 46 105 109 124 141 19 31 64 98 100 148 77 108 125 186 173 283 20 39 46 78 59 86 13 8 69 34 126 58 107 45 118 57 110 111 -3 21 -10 25 -78 34 l-75 10 -5 45 c-5 42 -7 45 -36 48 -26 3 -33 -1 -42 -25z"/><path d="M754 616 c-40 -19 -88 -39 -108 -46 -43 -14 -45 -30 -7 -72 25 -28 33 -31 80 -30 39 1 54 -3 58 -15 7 -18 -30 -140 -58 -192 -36 -67 6 -93 135 -84 l86 6 0 -26 c0 -14 -4 -37 -10 -51 -5 -14 -8 -26 -6 -26 7 0 110 68 129 85 11 10 17 30 17 60 0 62 -22 70 -150 57 -52 -5 -98 -6 -103 -2 -4 3 3 31 16 61 13 30 32 78 42 108 10 30 28 70 41 89 26 38 30 63 14 93 -17 31 -91 25 -176 -15z"/></g></svg>')
    response.headers.set('content-type', 'image/svg+xml')
    return response
  }
  
  // Default path
  if (pathname === '/') {
    url.pathname = '/s/' + config_obj['index'].slice(23)
  }

  // Prohibit other Craft.do share pages
  else if (pathname.startsWith('/s/')) {
    url.pathname = "/404"
  }

  // Proxy index blocks pages
  else if (pathname.startsWith('/b/')) {
    url.pathname = '/s/' + config_obj['index'].slice(23) + pathname
  }
  
  // TODO: There is an unresolved issue here
  // External pages url is troublesome to deal with.
  else if (pathname.includes('/x/')) {
    // url.pathname = '/s/' + config_obj['index'].slice(23) + pathname
    return Response.redirect('https://' + MY_DOMAIN, 301)
  }

  // Proxy js
  else if (pathname.startsWith('/share/') && pathname.endsWith('.js')) {
    response = await fetch(url)
    let body = await response.text()
    // replace all js files domain
    response = new Response(body.replace(/www.craft.do/g, MY_DOMAIN), response)
    response.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/x-javascript')
  }

  // Proxy images
  else if (pathname.startsWith('/img/')) {
    // Proxy api.craft.do, pages preview api
    // This code can proxy "MY_DOMAIN/img/<pathname>" --> "api.craft.do/render/preview/<slug>"
    url.host = 'api.craft.do'

    let path_name = pathname.slice(5)

    let img_slug = config_obj[path_name].slice(23)
    url.pathname = pathname.replace(pathname, '/render/preview/' + img_slug)

    // Cache images
    const cacheImage = `https://${url.host}${url.pathname}`
    let response = await fetch(url.href, {
      cf: {
        // Always cache this fetch regardless of content type
        // for a max of 86400 seconds before revalidating the resource
        cacheTtl: 86400,
        cacheEverything: true,
        //Enterprise only feature, see Cache API for other plans
        cacheKey: cacheImage,
      },
    })
    // Reconstruct the Response object to make its headers mutable.
    response = new Response(response.body, response)
    // Set cache control headers to cache on browser for 25 minutes
    response.headers.set("Cache-Control", "max-age=1500")
    return response
  }

  // Disable Craft log.
  else if (pathname.startsWith('/api/log/')) {
    return new Response('Disable loging.')
  }

  // Proxy comment API.
  else if (pathname.startsWith('/api/') && (pathname.includes('submitAnon'))) {
    const init = {
      body: request.body,
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
      },
    }
    const response = await fetch(url.href, init)
    const resp_json = await response.json()
    const resp_str = JSON.stringify(resp_json)

    // Telegram notify
    const comment_message = resp_json.comments[0].content
    const craft_slug = pathname.split("/")[5]
    const craft_url = 'https://www.craft.do/s/' + craft_slug
    const comment_slug = findJsonKey(config_obj, craft_url)
    const tg_message = 'Comment URL:\n' 
      + 'https://' + MY_DOMAIN + '/' + comment_slug 
      + '\n\n' 
      + 'Comment Message:\n' + comment_message
    await sendToTelegram(tg_message)

    return new Response(resp_str)
  }

  else {
    try {
      let urlIndexSlug = null
      if (pathname.startsWith('/en/') || pathname.startsWith('/p/') || pathname.startsWith('/page/')) {
        urlIndexSlug = pathname.split("/")[1] + '/' + pathname.split("/")[2]
      } else {
        urlIndexSlug = pathname.split("/")[1]
      }

      let configPath = config_obj[urlIndexSlug].slice(23)
      url.pathname = '/s/' + configPath

      console.log(url.pathname)

      if (typeof(configPath) == "undefined") { throw new Error('404 not found: ' + configPath) }
    } catch (error) {
      if (pathname.startsWith('/api/') || pathname.endsWith('.css') || pathname.endsWith('.webmanifest') || pathname.endsWith('.svg')) {
        // nothing
      } else {
        url.pathname = '/404'
        // return new Response(error.message)
      }
    }
  }

  class AttributeRewriter {
    element(element) {
      if (element.getAttribute('property') === 'og:url') {
        element.setAttribute('content', 'https://' + MY_DOMAIN + pathname)
      }
      if (element.getAttribute('property') === 'og:image') {
        if (pathname === '/') { pathname = '/index' }
        element.setAttribute('content', 'https://' + MY_DOMAIN + '/img' + pathname)
      }
      if (element.getAttribute('name') === 'luki:api-endpoint') {
        element.setAttribute('content', 'https://' + MY_DOMAIN + '/api/')
      }
      if (element.getAttribute('lang') === 'en') {
        element.setAttribute('lang', LANG)
      }
      if (element.getAttribute('rel') === 'icon') {
        element.setAttribute('href', FAVICON_URL)
      }
      if (element.getAttribute('rel') === 'apple-touch-icon') {
        element.setAttribute('href', FAVICON_URL)
      }
    }
  }
  class RemoveElement {
    element(element) {
      element.remove()
    }
  }
  async function rewriteHTML(res) {
    res.headers.delete("Content-Security-Policy")
    return new HTMLRewriter()
      .on('body', new BodyRewriter())
      .on('head', new HeadRewriter())
      .on('html', new AttributeRewriter())
      .on('meta', new AttributeRewriter())
      .on('link', new AttributeRewriter())
      .on('meta[name="robots"]', new RemoveElement())   // SEO
      .on('head>style', new RemoveElement())   // Remove fonts
      .on('script[src="https://www.craft.do/assets/js/analytics2.js"]', new RemoveElement())    // Delete analytics js
      .transform(res)
  }

  let method = request.method
  let request_headers = request.headers
  let new_request_headers = new Headers(request_headers)

  new_request_headers.set('Host', url.hostname)
  new_request_headers.set('Referer', url.hostname)

  let original_response = await fetch(url.href, {
    method: method,
    headers: new_request_headers
  })

  let response_headers = original_response.headers
  let new_response_headers = new Headers(response_headers)
  let status = original_response.status

  response = new Response(original_response.body, {
    status,
    headers: new_response_headers
  })

  // If you want change anything in response.
  let text = await response.text()

  // Return modified response.
  let modified_response = new Response(text, {
    status: response.status,
    statusText: response.statusText,
    headers: response.headers
  })

  if (pathname.startsWith('/share/static/js/') && (pathname.includes('codehighlight'))) {
    return modified_response
  } else {
    return rewriteHTML(modified_response)
  }
}

async function configParser() {
  // Delete string "https://www.craft.do/s/"
  let config_slug = CONFIG_URL.slice(23)
  const api_url = 'https://www.craft.do/api/share/' + config_slug
  const init = {
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    },
  }
  const config_response = await fetch(api_url, init)       // Get www.craft.do/api/share/<slug> content.
  const response_json = await config_response.json()       // Convert the content to json format (string).
  const content_json = response_json.blocks[1].content     // Get the json data of the first block in the body.
  const content_str = JSON.stringify(content_json)         // Convert json to string.
  // Handle escape characters.
  const config_json = content_str.replace(/\\t/g, '').replace(/\\n/g, '').replace(/\\/g, '').replace('"{', '{').replace('}"', '}')
  let config_obj = JSON.parse(config_json)
  return config_obj
}

async function sendToTelegram(message) {
  const tgUrl = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + TG_TOKEN + "/sendMessage"
  const init = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      "chat_id": TG_CHAT_ID,
      "text": message
    })
  }
  await fetch(tgUrl, init)
  // const response = await fetch(tgUrl, init)
  // const resp_text = await response.text()
  // return new Response(resp_text)
}

function findJsonKey(obj, value, compare = (a, b) => a === b) {
  return Object.keys(obj).find(k => compare(obj[k], value))
}

class BodyRewriter {
  element(element) {
    // Append your html
    element.append(`
    
    `, {
      html: true
    })
  }
}
class HeadRewriter {
  element(element) {
    element.append(`
    <style>
    /* Hide the Craft "Login in" button in comment board. */
    .sc-CtfFt {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
    .hGGlzy {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
    </style>
    `, {
      html: true
    })
  }
}
```

The only thing I added in his code was the value for const My_DOMAIN and const CONFIG_URL.

When I try to open the URL where it should deploy: https://knu-salin.vinceimbat.workers.dev/, I get Error 1101 Worker threw exception. Upon inspecting the debug console, this is what I saw:

[Uncaught (in promise) TypeError and Uncaught (in response) TypeError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vunD.png)

Was I doing something wrong? Or is there somethign wrong with his code?

Answer (score 0):

The error message says:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'slice')
  at fetchAndApply (worker.js:56)
```

So, let's see what's on line 56. That appears to be:

```js
    url.pathname = '/s/' + config_obj['index'].slice(23)
```

The error message is telling us that `config_obj['index']` was undefined, and so trying to access `config_obj['index'].slice` is an error.

If `config_obj['index']` is undefined, that means that the property `index` is missing from `config_obj`. But where did `config_obj` come from? Up above, we see:

```js
  const config_obj = await configParser()
```

OK, so the `configParser()` function creates this object. Let's look at that function.

```js
async function configParser() {
  // Delete string "https://www.craft.do/s/"
  let config_slug = CONFIG_URL.slice(23)
  const api_url = 'https://www.craft.do/api/share/' + config_slug
  const init = {
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
    },
  }
  const config_response = await fetch(api_url, init)       // Get www.craft.do/api/share/<slug> content.
  const response_json = await config_response.json()       // Convert the content to json format (string).
  const content_json = response_json.blocks[1].content     // Get the json data of the first block in the body.
  const content_str = JSON.stringify(content_json)         // Convert json to string.
  // Handle escape characters.
  const config_json = content_str.replace(/\\t/g, '').replace(/\\n/g, '').replace(/\\/g, '').replace('"{', '{').replace('}"', '}')
  let config_obj = JSON.parse(config_json)
  return config_obj
}
```

We can see that, based on the URL you specified for `CONFIG_URL`, this code will compute the url `https://www.craft.do/api/share/9Q1QIOQrvZNnNf`, fetch that URL, parse it as JSON, and return the result.

If you [visit that URL](https://www.craft.do/api/share/9Q1QIOQrvZNnNf), you see it does indeed return JSON. However, the JSON does not contain a top-level property called `index`. Hence the failure you saw.

It seems like this is either some sort of error in your craft.do configuration or a bug in the worker code, but to determine that, you'd have to talk to the developer.